# How to give percentage(%) to button width in windows phone app 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing one windows phone app.but my problem is how to give % to width of the button.

```
<Button x:Name="Recharge" Content="RECHARGE" Background="Red" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,42" RenderTransformOrigin="0.514,1.408"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="70" Click="Recharge_Click" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="25" Width="390" >
```

in the above code I gave width=50% but it not working. I am declare width=390 statically.but I want to  give like width=40% like this.

actually what happend is in 4 inches windows phone its looking good,but in large phones(5 inches,6 inches) phones its not proper design.how to fix this issue.

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a grid. With a grid you can add columns, then place the button in the middle column (or left or right what you want).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="Recharge" Grid.Column="1" Content="RECHARGE" Background="Red" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Click="Recharge_Click" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="25" >
</Grid>
```